# What is the correct terminology usage regarding "downconversion" and "correlation"?

Tags: communication, digital-communications

I've recently taken a digital communications course.

To provide some background to my question: In passband, it was explained that the incoming signal r(t) is "split" into different channels, and correlated with known reference signals, or basis functions. This is illustrated below (from Digital Communications by Bernard Sklar)

[image]

I think I understand above theory, and how you utilize orthogonality of basis functions to express signals as a linear combination, then introduce things as signal space, etc. However, I also see many referring to the mixer operations in the above pictures as "downconversion" - instead of "correlation". A less mathematical representation, and more practical, is the following picture ([article source](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/dsp-basics-of-digital-down-conversion-digital-signal-processing/)):

[image]

The article, source of picture above, describes the first RF mixer as a downconversion to IF - which I agree with because we are not interested yet in decomposing the signal into orthogonal components by correlation. However, the article also refers to the two later IF mixers as the "second downconversion". And this is the heart of the issue, perhaps I am being picky, but to me, it would be much more descriptive to refer to that operation as the "correlation" than "downconversion". Granted, down-conversion is a side-effect since we are multiplying two sinusoids, but really what we're after is to "extract" the I and Q components by using correlation. Would you agree?

**Fundamentally, in light of above rant, my question is**: How would you define the following operations in a communication system, especially in relation to each other: Downconversion and correlation. Or perhaps they are used interchangeably?

Comment: Rhetorical question: If you have a phase-locked local oscillator (Oscillator2), is there actually a *mathematical* difference between downconversion to DC and correlation with the local oscillator's signal?

Comment: Hi @nanofarad , thanks. I am not sure. Oscillator2 is connected to two mixers, if we only were interested in another downconversion, we would only need one mixer right? So there is another purpose here, or an added purpose. Also, a "regular" downconversion, such as Oscillator 1, is not by definition followed by an integration (required for correlation), implemented by the LPF after oscillator2 mixers (I think)... Maybe more after a sanity check, do you think my question has some merit, do you understand my confusion, or am I being silly?

Comment: The reason for the 2 mixers is that they give you the I & Q components of the signal.  You need the I&Q signals to determine the amplitude and phase information of an incoming signal.  While the second mixer may be one oscillator, it is providing two signals, 90 deg apart, to the two mixers.

Comment: Who says that our downconversion is to get a purely real signal? By having I and Q components, you're essentially downconverting as if your local oscillator produced a complex signal \$e^{j2\pi f}\$, rather than a purely real signal having both positive and negative frequency components.

Comment: Thanks SteveSh - I agree. My questions is more related to how correctly refer to these two mixers. Would you say they perform correlation or downconversion? Thanks

Comment: In that diagram, I would call them mixers as they are downconverting the two channels into a lower frequency.  Hence the LPF in the path.

Comment: And your bottom diagram applies to many types of systems.  It is just as good of representation for the front end of a radar system as it is for a communication channel.

Comment: SteveSh - thanks. I agree in that they are mixers. But as described in my post, one source (Digital Communications, Bernard Sklar) refers to them as a "correlation" process, and another (linked article) as a "downconversion" process, I wonder which one is most accurate. Perhaps the two terms are used as synonyms in the industry (I am new to communications industry). Thanks

Comment: @nanofarad, thanks. I am not sure I understand how this related to the original question, I'll give it some thought, and perhaps something clicks.. cheers. EDIT no 2 - Ok I see what you mean. Good point... Need to think about it. Thanks

Comment: Correlation is a mathematical description of the operation, while down-conversion is a radio engineering description, inherited from superheterodyne receiver practice since the 1930s (for AM, you only need the I path; for SSB the Q path is useful too). Note the integrator has become a low pass filter in the radio description... Note also that downconversion doesn't HAVE to imply baseband output; it may be to some other frequency like a 455kHz or 10.7MHz IF, in which case the LPF is a bandpass.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianDrummond - this is the type of answer I was looking for. I guess a sanity check on how they are used in the industry... I am new to StackExchange and I don't think I can mark a comment as a correct answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Downconversion always involves multiplication with a simple periodic signal, such as a single frequency sine or square wave. The purpose is to reduce the high frequency signal down to something lower that can be managed more easily. This rarely comes right down to DC, an IF output is usually used, bandpass filtering the output of the mixer. The mixing frequency is chosen to be something other than the input centre frequency.

Correlation is more general and involves multiplication with an arbitrary signal, which is usually non-sinusoidal, such as a Walsh function, or an m-sequence. The purpose is to extract signals of the same shape as the reference waveform, and usually comes right down to DC, lowpass filtering or integrating the output of the mixer. The reference waveform is chosen to match the expected input.

A conventional diode ring, double balanced, RF mixer is generally good enough for downconversion. Correlation usually happens at lower frequencies when mixers that can better handle wideband arbitrary signals are used, which these days are digital multipliers, once the IF signal has been digitised.

Comment: Downconversion can be done with square wave local oscillators too, provided the input frequency is bandpass filtered.